# Why is my ONE grease pencil layer transparent against the background?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

So I have a character made from grease pencil strokes. I want to place a static background image behind him, so I *Add* - *Image* - *Background*, and place this jpg of space. It is behind all of the grease pencil layers, and yet ONE of my objects is now transparent to the background... I could not find any problems with materials or layers, so I'm completely confused, especially since the portions of the legs that are behind the shirt make that section opaque for some reason. Any suggestions?[image][image][image]

Comment: maybe you could look in the Data tab (green squiggle) under `Strokes`, and make sure that the `Stroke Depth Order` is set to `3D Location`

Comment: Yep, tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: right, actually adding the image using the `Image As Planes` option instead of `Background` should do the trick

Comment: Okay, that fixed the transparency issue, but the picture is imported as a plain grey plane rather than the image! I tried with a PNG and a JPG, both are uniform grey.

Comment: you gotta be in material preview or in render view for textures to show up (lil balls in top right of viewport)

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot for your help!